# How to merge empty field with the following value in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge two rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941116/merge-two-rows-in-sql)

I have the following values in table:

```
---------------------
row1 | row2 | row3
---------------------
val1 |      |
     | val2 | 
     |      | val3
```

How do I merge these rows?

```
$qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");

while($row = msyql_fetch_assoc($qu)){
$rowone = $row['row1'];
$rowtwo = $row['row2'];
$rowtre = $row['row3'];

echo $rowone." ".$rowtwo." ".$rowtre;
}
```

I want this to return

```
val1 val2 val3
```

I have a theory about how this is possible but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an aggregate function on all columns.

```
SELECT MAX(row1), MAX(row2), MAX(row3)
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(col1,col2,col3) as colname
FROM tableName
```

Comment: He'll get "value1 NULL NULL", "NULL value2 NULL", "NULL NULL value3"

Comment: SELECT concat(ifnull(col1,''),ifnull(col2,''),ifnull(col3,'')) as colname
FROM tableName