# Suggestions on T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to work out a way to display all the data on the same row for each document number.

I have attached a screenshot of the table output. Basically the database presents the components of each product on separate lines, and I want to put them all onto one line.

Can anyone suggest a solution ?

```sql
select DOC_NUMBER , PRODUCT_CODE , MATL_1 , MATL_2 , MATL_3 , MATL_4 
from PRODUCT_STRUCTURE
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Sample data and expected results, along with your attempts, will help us help you.

Comment: `GROUP BY DOC_NUMBER` and `SELECT MAX()` for all other columns

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941248/1220550