# Re-arrange or Merge multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Assuming I have a table containing the following information:

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | B | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | C | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | D |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | E |
| 1 | NULL | F | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | X | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | Y | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | Z |

is there a way I can perform a select on the table to get the following

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | D |
| 1 | NULL | C | E |
| 1 | NULL | F | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | X | Z |
| 2 | NULL | Y | NULL |

Comment: You need to explain the necessary logic  here

Comment: My question is more similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941116/merge-two-rows-in-sql . But i have to do that with multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get rows where column B is not null:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t
WHERE t.ColumnB is not null
```